# ES6 Type to represent a key-value object that can be inverted

Tags: javascript, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I have the following JS object:

```
var obj={
  "j":"jack",
  "f":"franck",
  "a":"amy",
};
```

Now I can write `obj[val]` , where `val` is in `j,f,a` to access the value of that key. I would like to know if they is a datastructure (in ES6) that would allow me to get the key from the value (eg write `obj.inverted()["jack"]` to get `j`).

I know I can do it by using `underscore` or a simple function, but I would like to know if they is some datastructure in ES6 that would give me this *feature* out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no such feature - you'll need to create an extra copy of the map with the keys and values inverted.

If using ES6 you should, of course, use a proper `Map` object rather than an `Object`:

```
var myMap = new Map([
  ['j', 'jack'],
  ['f', 'franck'],
  ['a', 'amy']
]);
var inverse = new Map();

for (let [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
    inverse.set(value, key);
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. Do you know if any other languages have such a feature ? And how it is called ?

Comment: @edi9999 I believe it's called a "bidirectional map"